# How to insert an external image in richtext editor in wagtail

Tags: wagtail

In wagtail RichtextField's editor, I can upload and insert an image without problem, however what if I want to insert an image from an external URL, what can I do? current Draftail editor doesn't provide such an option.

I tried the following options already:

- **"embed" button in RichtextField edtior**. obviously it doesn't work for most external image URL, maybe it would work for some selected sources with oEmbed. Most of the time it gives error "Cannot find an embed for this URL."
- **demo site provided by Michael Yin**
  https://blog.michaelyin.info/wagtail-blog-demo-now-available/. The RichtextField editor has exactly the same buttons, and "embed" button gives exactly the same error. So this can rule out problem of my own configurare
- **draftail editor** at https://www.draftail.org/ actually has a button to insert image by external URL, and the demo works very well.

so my question: why did Wagtail remove the support to insert external image URL, and how can I insert an image by URL in RichtextField editor?